# How to find several fields of a foreign key in a join table in Node.js Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a **Node.js** application with **Express**, **Sequelize** as ORM and **PostgreSQL** for the database. In this app I have `candidate` model and `mission` model as below.

```
'use strict';
    const {
        Model
    } = require('sequelize');
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
        class candidat extends Model {

        static associate(models) {
            this.belongsToMany(models.mission, {
                through: "candidat_mission",
                foreignKey: "candidatId",
                otherKey: "idMission",
            });
        }
    }
    candidat.init({
        candidatId: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            isEmail: true,
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
        },

    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'candidat',
        tableName: 'candidat',
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    return candidat;
};

'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class mission extends Model {

        static associate(models) {
 
            this.belongsToMany(models.candidat, {
                through: "candidat_mission",
                foreignKey: "idMission",
                otherKey: "candidatId",
            })
        }
    }
    mission.init({
        idMission: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        aliasTitle: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'mission',
        tableName: 'mission',
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    return mission;
};
```

These two models are linked in many-to-many by a `candidate_mission` join table. In this model, I added fields like a foreign key which points to another table, that of `users`.

```
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class candidat_mission extends Model {

        static associate(models) {
            this.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: "fk_user" });
        }
    }
    candidat_mission.init({
        candidatMissionId: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        candidatId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: { tableName: 'candidat' },
                key: "candidatId",
            },
        },
        idMission: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: { tableName: 'mission' },
                key: "idMission",
            },
        },
        fk_user: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: { tableName: 'user' },
                key: "userId",
            },
        },
    
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'candidat_mission',
        tableName: 'candidat_mission',
        timestamps: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    return candidat_mission;
};
```

When I make a "GET" request, I do have the information from the candidate_mission table (if a candidate is linked to this mission), but for the user it only returns the ID and I would like it to return all the fields present in the Users model, what can I do?

Here, my function in the mission controller which allows to add a candidate to this mission :

```
const addCandidats = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const mission = await Mission.findByPk(req.body.idMission);

        if (mission) {
            const candidat = await Candidat.findByPk(req.body.candidatId);
            if (candidat) {
                mission.addCandidat(candidat, 
                    {through: {
                        fk_user: req.body.fk_user && req.body.fk_user
                    }});
                return res.status(200).send(mission);
            } else {
                console.log("Candidat non trouvé");
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Mission non trouvée!")
            return null;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Currently, my query returns me this :
"candidat_mission":

```
{
  "candidatMissionId": 2,
  "candidatId": 1,
  "idMission": 7,
  "fk_user": 1,
  "createdAt": "2023-02-14T10:34:08.302Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T15:06:10.232Z"
},
```

And i want it to come back to me :

```
"candidat_mission": 
{
 "candidatMissionId": 2,
                "candidatId": 1,
                "idMission": 7,
                "fk_user": {
            "userId": 1,
            "email": "blabla@gmail.com",
            "name": "blabla"
        },
                "createdAt": "2023-02-14T10:34:08.302Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-02-14T15:06:10.232Z"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After associating 2 models, we have to query again to get the object along with the relationship.

```
await mission.addCandidat(candidat, 
                    {through: {
                        fk_user: req.body.fk_user && req.body.fk_user
                    }});

const result = await CandidatMission.findOne({
  where: { candidatId: req.body.candidatId, idMission: req.body.idMission },
  include: models.user,
})

return res.status(200).send(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Instead of having the `CandidatMission` link with the user when I add a candidate to a mission, can I have it when I retrieve the data from a mission directly? As my mission is linked to the `Candidate` model and not to the `CandidateMission` model, I cannot use include to add User to the `CandidateMission`. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: You can try `Mission.find({ include: models.user })` and it will return mission with users as an Array, since they are many2many relationship.

Comment: It's the `CandidatMission` join table which is linked to the `User` table, the `Mission` table is not linked to the user but when I make a GET request for my mission I do have the `CandidatMission` data displayed except that the foreign key of the user only displays the Id of the user and I would like it to display all the data present in the `User` table. Is It possible to do this when I make a GET request of the table `Mission` ?

Comment: We have to add another relationship on `Mission` model `this.belongsToMany(models.user, { through: "candidat_mission", foreignKey: "idMission", otherKey: "fk_user" })` then use `Mission.find({ include: models.user })`